# How to properly use the constructor when using swing

Tags: java, swing, constructor

I'm creating a class in which will create a user interface using swing. I am using a constructor was wondering if I'm actually using it properly. Should all parts that will be in the JFrame (like buttons and text fields) be created inside of the constructor? My main concern here is that when I instantiate the code, it says that it is unused as everything is done via the constructor.

Here is my code, i have removed most of it as it is mostly just methods called by the constructor that create the components of the JFrame and a few methods that are called inside of an action listener for the button. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class saveToFile extends JFrame {
    private JTextArea filename;
    Vector sentMessages;
    Vector receivedMessages;
    public saveToFile(Vector sent, Vector received) {
        sentMessages = sent;
        receivedMessages = received;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        this.setSize(400, 200);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Save Conversation");
        panel = fileName(panel);
        panel = saveButton(panel);
        this.add(panel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Please make classes start with a Capital as that is the convention. Makes reading better... saveToFile -> SaveToFile

Comment: But other than that is my use of the constructor correct?

Comment: I don't think that your question is appropriate for this site as you're not asking about code that doesn't work but rather more general "best practices".

Comment: It is reasonable for the constructor to instantiate all the GUI components, but it is odd for it to invoke `this.setVisible(true)`.  That's performing behavior, not setting state, since it has side effects on the display.  Pull that out and let whoever instantiates your class invoke it.  Not only would that be better form, but it would probably resolve the compiler warning.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Comment: Well, there is no real problem creating the components if the constructor of a class. However, you should NOT be creating a class that extends JFrame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html). The `LabelDemo` code will show you how to better structure your code so that 1) you don't extend JFrame, 2) the GUI code is created on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: Subclassing JFrame is OK.  A little suboptimal (I prefer subclassing JPanel) but it's OK.  That GUI code needs to be accessed on the EDT is a very good point.  However that doesn't apply directly to the ctor, since the caller of the ctor is responsible for that.